# Do not plot some counts with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

As a reproducible example, use

```
library(tidyverse)
iris_count <- count(iris, Species)

iris_count %>%
  mutate(Species2 = ifelse(Species == "setosa", NA, as.character(Species))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Species2, -n), n)) +
  geom_col(na.rm = TRUE)
```

I want to remove the `NA` from the plot, but option `na.rm = TRUE` doesn't seem to do what I want in this case.

Comment: Why not just omit them from the data? `mutate(...) %>% na.omit %>% ggplot...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scale_x_discrete` and argument `na.translate = FALSE`. From `scale_x_discrete` documentation :

> `na.translate` Unlike continuous scales, discrete scales can easily show missing values, and do so by default. If you want to remove missing values from a discrete scale, specify na.translate = FALSE.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
iris_count <- count(iris, Species)

iris_count %>%
  mutate(Species2 = ifelse(Species == "setosa", NA, as.character(Species))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Species2, -n), n)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE)
```